# Flutter dropdownMenue with conditions

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, initialization

I'm creating two dropdown menues with the condition that the values in the second dropdown menu changes according to selected value in the first dropdown menu. I however keep getting this errro that `LateInitializationError: Field 'selecItem' has not been initialized.` This happens after I select the value in the first dropdown menu.

I don't understand it. can someone please explain it to me?

```
late List<String> department;
late String? selectedDepartment;
late List<String> adminTitle;
late List<String> technicalTitle;

@override
void initState(){
super.initState();
department = [
      widget.technicalDept,
      widget.adminDept
    ];
selectedDepartment = department[0];
if (selectedDepartment == department[0]) {
      selecItem = [
        widget.selectTitleString,
        widget.backEndDevString,
        widget.frontEndDevString,
        widget.networkEngString,
        widget.computerEngString,
      ];
      values = technicalTitle[0];
    }
if (selectedDepartment == department[1]) {
      selecItem = [
        widget.selectTitleString,
        widget.regionalAdminString,
        widget.sectorAdminString
      ];
      values = adminTitle[0];
    }
}

**in the build widget**
Row( children: [
         SizedBox(
            width: screenWidth * 0.1,//I defined media query for this
            child: Text("${widget.departmentString}:")),
         DropdownButton<String>(
            value: selectedDepartment,
            items: department.map((e) {
               return DropdownMenuItem(value: e, child: Text(e));
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedDepartment = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        selectedDepartment != department[0]
                            ? Row(
                                children: [
                                  SizedBox(
                                      width: screenWidth * 0.1,
                                      child:
                                          Text("${widget.selectTitleString}:")),
                                  DropdownButton<String>(
                                    value: values,
                                    items: selecItem!.map((e) {
                                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                                          value: e, child: Text(e));
                                    }).toList(),
                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        values = value;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )
                            : const SizedBox()
                      ],
                    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

your code failed due to an uninitialized late variable (selecItem)
Make selecItem nullable and initializing it in initState and within the onChanged callback of the first dropdown to ensure it's always set before use

```
  List<String>? selecItem;
```

Here is sample

```html
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String technicalDept;
  final String adminDept;
  final String selectTitleString;
  final String backEndDevString;
  final String frontEndDevString;
  final String networkEngString;
  final String computerEngString;
  final String regionalAdminString;
  final String sectorAdminString;
  final String departmentString;

  const MyWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.technicalDept,
    required this.adminDept,
    required this.selectTitleString,
    required this.backEndDevString,
    required this.frontEndDevString,
    required this.networkEngString,
    required this.computerEngString,
    required this.regionalAdminString,
    required this.sectorAdminString,
    required this.departmentString,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  late List<String> department;
  String? selectedDepartment;
  List<String>? selecItem;
  String? values;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    department = [widget.technicalDept, widget.adminDept];
    selectedDepartment = department[0];
    updateTitlesBasedOnDepartment();
  }

  void updateTitlesBasedOnDepartment() {
    if (selectedDepartment == department[0]) {
      selecItem = [
        widget.selectTitleString,
        widget.backEndDevString,
        widget.frontEndDevString,
        widget.networkEngString,
        widget.computerEngString,
      ];
    } else if (selectedDepartment == department[1]) {
      selecItem = [
        widget.selectTitleString,
        widget.regionalAdminString,
        widget.sectorAdminString,
      ];
    }
    values = selecItem?.first; 
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            SizedBox(width: screenWidth * 0.1, child: Text("${widget.departmentString}:")),
            DropdownButton<String>(
              value: selectedDepartment,
              items: department.map((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedDepartment = value;
                  updateTitlesBasedOnDepartment();
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        if (selectedDepartment == department[0] || selectedDepartment == department[1]) 
          Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(width: screenWidth * 0.1, child: Text("${widget.selectTitleString}:")),
              DropdownButton<String>(
                value: values,
                items: selecItem?.map((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    values = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

You can make a sample call here

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Dropdown Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(
            technicalDept: 'Technical Department',
            adminDept: 'Administrative Department',
            selectTitleString: 'Select Title',
            backEndDevString: 'Backend Developer',
            frontEndDevString: 'Frontend Developer',
            networkEngString: 'Network Engineer',
            computerEngString: 'Computer Engineer',
            regionalAdminString: 'Regional Administrator',
            sectorAdminString: 'Sector Administrator',
            departmentString: 'Department',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. No error occurs but the second dropdown doesn't drop down anything

Comment: I just tested the sample again and it worked fine... could you test again

I will update with full code

Comment: It still doesn't work. The thing is I don't understand why you are equating selectedDepartment == department[0] || selectedDepartment == department[1]. My equation is if selectedDepartment != department[0]

Comment: The initial issue you have is the error LateInitializationError: Field 'selecItem' has not been initialized. when you select a value in the drop down.  I highlighted why you are getting the error and created a sample case which I posted .

Comment: If you copy my full code and test, selecting from first item dynamically update the second drop down which I believe that is what you want to achieve

Comment: If you have another issue with logic, then you can explain what you want to achieve then I can update the logic to fit in to your case

Comment: Don't worry, I've found a different solution to it. Thanks anyway